# Append text conditionally to a JS file

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

We are building our project with MSBuild - it's a typescript project.
One of the current requirements is to add a text conditionally to before or after some file. So currently files are added and built like below:

```
<OurBundle Include="SomeFile.ts" />...
<OurBundle Include="SomeOtherFile.ts" />...

<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <ReadLinesFromFile File="%(OurBundle.Identity)" >
      <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="jsLines" />
    </ReadLinesFromFile>
    <WriteLinesToFile File="scriptbundle.js" Lines="@(jsLines)" Overwrite="true" />
</Target>
```

What I like to have is something like this:

```
<OurBundle Include="SomeFile.ts" />...
<OurBundle Include="SomeOtherFile.ts" AddDetails="true" />...
```

and update the build script in a way that when the AddDetails property / attribute is set to true, I read from another file and add the contents of that file to the built JS. Alternatively (using a similar approach) we can pre-build these files with the attribute and then merge them with the rest. I just need to find a way to conditionally select the ones with the attribute and figure out how do I merge the content from the details file with the built file.

Comment: You're stating this a bit too much as an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) making it hard to understand. Please tell what you want to do, what the end result should be, not how you think it gets implemented in msbuild. If I get it correctly, you only want to append the content of SomeOtherFile.ts to scriptbundle.js if AddDetails is True? Who/what decides the value of AddDetails? Is it available globally for the build process? Or do you mean there are multiple 'other files' and each of those has a seperate corresponding AddDetails?

Comment: I want to conditonally append the contents of another file to the beginning or end of another built js file. In the end it should have 1 js file, with the details line separating them.

I want to append the contents of another file after "SomeOtherFile.ts" because add details is true.

Comment: So just `<OurBundle Include="SomeOtherFile.ts" Condition="'$(AddDetails)' == 'True'" />` probably?